# Pardot engagement studio is sending emails with a delay

Tags: email, form, pardot

I set up engagement studio for our newsletter opt in. After submitting a form, the user is added to a list which is the starting point of the engagement studio. Then the user is supposed to receive an email with a confirmation link. But the email is sent with a delay of about 20 minutes. How can I make it that the email is sent immediately after the form is submitted and without a delay?

Answer (score 2):

Engagement Studio and most Pardot routines are not real time, they usually happen within a few minutes but can sometimes take longer.  If you want immediate responses for your signups, then you should add a 'Completion Action' step to the Pardot form/form-handler to send your auto-responder email.  These are sent immediately.